# How to configure express to serve angular app in production?

Tags: angular, express, production-environment

There is common problem with client-side routing mechanism: once it is deployed, so called "deep links" like `host/deep/deeper/deepest/link/1` spits out 404 Not Found rahter then gets propagated to the `index.html` and resovled properly to a certain component.

How do I configure it?

I tried:

```
app.use(express.static(root)); // root folder of the project
app.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, root,'index.html')));
```

...and yet it works only with base url; all others are rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.use(express.static(root)); // root folder of the project
```

This means a middleware function with no mount path. This code is executed for every request to the router

try to use look like this

```
  app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../root')));

  app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../root/index.html'));
  });
```

The complete example is here
https://github.com/mdshohelrana/mean-stack/blob/master/server/app.ts